# How to reference elements added by jQuery .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this function to add images to a div element:

```
function pasteImages(url,id) {

    jQuery("#photodiv").append("<div id='photoid"+ id +"'>")
    jQuery("#photodiv").append("<img src=" + url + " height='140' width='140'>");
    jQuery("#photodiv").append("<button type='button' onclick='deleteImage("+ id + ");'>Verwijderen</button>");
    jQuery("#photodiv").append("</div>");
}
```

The url and id attribute are retrieved using an AJAX call. The button calls a function to delete the  image (after the image was successfully deleted from the DB)

After the image was successfully deleted the succes: function gets called:

```
.......success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                var photoarray = JSON.parse(data);

                var photoid2remove = "#photoid" + photoarray[0].photoid;
                jQuery(photoid2remove).empty();
            }
```

All works fine, but nothing gets deleted. I've tried a static id OR class but it's not doing anything. When I check the source I can't find the appended div's anywhere. So how can I refer to the div's I've added with the first function?

Any clue?

Comment: Check the source or inspect element? Because the two would give different results.

Comment: do you have a link or a jsfiddle we could play with?

Comment: Are you sure that `data` contains what you expect, and that `photoid2remove` exactly matches the originally-added ID?

Comment: @Maxzeroedge I've checked the source and inspected the element (div with id=photodiv) Both aren't showing the added div's (client side)

Comment: @yochannah no link yet

Comment: @PaulRoub I've checked the JSON(data) and it shows the correct ID. I've even hacked it and tried a different div (which is showing in the source) and as I would suspect it gets removed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unclosed HTML tags in `append` calls are automatically given closing tags. Therefore, the code

```
jQuery("#photodiv").append("<div id='photoid"+ id +"'>")
```

is the same as

```
jQuery("#photodiv").append("<div id='photoid"+ id +"'></div>")
```

Thus, your `<img>` and `<button>` are appended to the `#photodiv` element, not the newly-created `<div>`. Removing the `<div>` doesn't remove the other elements, because they're not in the `<div>`.

You must either put all of your HTML into a single `append` call, or create elements using the `jQuery` function and call `append` on those:

```
var newDiv = jQuery("<div>", { id: "photoid"+ id });
var newImg = jQuery("<img>", { src:url, height:140, width:140 });
var newButton = jQuery("<button>", { type:'button', text: "Verwijderen", onclick: "deleteImage("+ id + ");" });

newDiv.append(newImg);
newDiv.append(newButton);

jQuery("#photodiv").append(newDiv);
```

Comment: It works!! Great explanation. After reading your answer I got it. I was adding everything to the photodiv instead of the newly created div.... Still one question, why isn't the source updated client side. After adding the div with image and button it's not shown in the source?

Comment: "View source" in your browser shows you the source code that was sent to your page as page-load time. A developer tool with "inspect element" functionality (present in the right-click menus of virtually all modern desktop browsers) will show you an HTML-style representation of the DOM as it exists at that moment.

Comment: I'm using the Safari Developer plugin and console prints are shown but when I look at the source the photodiv stays empty. But when I use the info inspect I can select the newly added div and I can see the actual elements. Learned another thing!